# How to set div to expand with transition on text change

Tags: html, css

I want to seamlessly expand my div (in a non-jarring way) when the text inside it changes:

The CSS `transition: all 2s ease;` is working great for colour changes, manually setting width, etc (as you can try out in the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tzjafc1a/2/) - click button to toggle width). but when the inner text of the div is changed the div just jumps to the new width without any transition.

How can I get the transition working when the inner text changes?

Thanks!

Comment: Would it be possible to update your JSFiddle so we can see how the div around the text jumps when changing width?

Comment: As mentioned below...you can't do this with pure CSS. Without a width being set the default initial width is `auto` and the replaced width is still `auto`. Even if the *computed* value of those is different, CSS can't transition to or from `auto`. You need JS.

Comment: Seconded - you should be able to do something simply like this with jQuery just fine.  By looks of your JSFiddle, you seem up to the task.

**Edit:** Does this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thechrisjordan/3Fc7D/23/) help?  I got it from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508605/how-can-i-transition-height-0-to-height-auto-using-css?rq=1).

Comment: I ended up using a different solution. I don't think this is very clean - but it works fine for what I need: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvLOzM

Answer (score 3):

Because the default width of the div will be `auto` (100%), it can't transition from `auto` to a numerical value.

Comment: Ok - but I don't think I'm changing the width to a numerical value. I'm simply adding or taking away text from inside it. I am never setting a pixel value. It just re-sizes by it's self to contain the text.

Comment: Yes but then the browser has to then rerender the div's width, it'll then set in a pixel value

Comment: Ok - but if I set a default width value the div no longer re-sizes at all. How can I make it re-size with a transition?

Comment: Try setting a `min-width`, see what that does and report back here

Comment: Nope - that just goes back to jumpy scaling. No transition.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think dynamically changing a width of an element depending on its content is possible, as there is no transition for content. The content of an element changes instantly and the width does not get a numerical value in your case - but adjusts.

A solution that can be sometimes applicable: Using a **function** to roughly calculate your text's width so that you'll be able to **set a numerical width for your element on change**.

Here's a simple one that I made.

```
function getTextWidth(text, css) {
    var e = $('<span></span>'); // dummy element
    e.css(css); // set properties
    e.text(text); // set test
    var width = e.appendTo($('body')).width(); // append and get width
    e.remove(); // remove from DOM
    return width;
}
```

Put together an [example of usage](https://jsfiddle.net/20o9jkvj/7/).

Answer (score 0):

Hi abagshaw try this script to solved your problem.

```js
var big = false;

$('#content').on('click', function(e) {
     if(!big)
     {
       
           $( this).animate({
    width: "600px"  }, 500 );
         this.innerHTML = "MORETEXTMORETEXTMORETEXTMORETEXTMORETEXTMORETEXTMORETEXT";
         
         big = true;
     }
     else
     {
        $( this).animate({
    width: "200px"  }, 500 );
         this.innerHTML = "LESSTEXTLESSTEXT";
         big = false;
     }
 });
```

```css
.ui.transitioning.button{
   transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;-webkit-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    width:200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.0.7/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ui transitioning teal button" id="content">LESSTEXTLESSTEXT</div>
```

Comment: That does work - but the issue is I might not nessecarily have only two states (maybe three or four) and I can't predict how big the box will be when it expands or shrinks so I need it to be able to do that for me.

Comment: @abagshaw Means you need multiple div or any element. ?

Comment: Thanks but I ended up solving this on my own. codepen.io/anon/pen/WvLOzM

Comment: For anyone interested I got it to work without any issues by using an "inner_div" with the text in consideration and auto width. Have the outer width initially fixed and not auto. Then upon a click calculate the necessary width in JS with new_width = document.getElementById('inner_div').offsetWidth. JS style your outer div bar with the new_width variable that you obtained. I'd normally post the solution here, but I used my code for a complex toolbox div within an interactive SVG with added complexities. If anyone upvotes this I will post the solution.